# Initialize 2d array to one value in initializer list c++

Tags: c++

I can create a private 2d vector in a class like

```cpp
std::vector<std::vector<bool>> currGrid;
```

and I can initialize it directly in the constructor like:

```cpp
MyClass::MyClass(std::uint8_t sizeX, std::uint8_t sizeY) :
    sizeX(sizeX),
    sizeY(sizeY),
    currGrid(sizeX, std::vector<bool>(sizeY, false))
{
}
```

I want to do a similar thing with an array, where the sizes are defined in the class like:

```cpp
  private:
    static constexpr uint8_t sizeX = 5;
    static constexpr uint8_t sizeY = 5;
    std::array<std::array<bool, sizeX>, sizeY> grid;
```

How would this initilization work in the class constructor?

```cpp
MyOtherClass::MyOtherClass():
    grid() //how should this look here if I want to set all values to false?
{
}
```

Comment: Well by default they would be default initialised to `false` anyway.

Comment: Yeah I'm getting some weird behavior where garbage is getting in there somehow. So I wanted to try and make it explicit.

Comment: Changes are if you're getting garbage in there you probably have some undefined behaviour. You should consider [edit]ing your question to include a [mcve], but from what you've put there, all elements in `grid` would be `false`